# Query last N rows based on ID in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a SQLite database in which I am trying to read the last 8 rows in database using ID.

I am having trouble with the query. Can't seem to get it right.

```
public String lastEightRows(){
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLORS};
    String result30 = " ";

    String where = "ORDER BY" + KEY_ROWID + "DESC LIMIT" +  8;
    //This is where I am not able to get the query right

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, where, null, null, null, null);

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iColors = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COLORS);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result30 = result30 + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iColors)  + " " + "\n";
    }

    return result30;
}
```

I got this error message

```
03-26 22:58:27.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DESC": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_colors FROM personsTable WHERE _id DESC LIMIT 8
```

Comment: what is ourDatabase? it's contentresolver or sqliteDatabase?

Comment: name of sqlitedatabase

Comment: what is your error?? do you debug your app??

Comment: 03-26 22:58:27.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1368): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "DESC": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id,  persons_colors FROM personsTable WHERE _id DESC LIMIT 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android SQLiteDatabase API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
>
> Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.

Try this code instead

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID + " DESC", "8");
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlitedatabase.query() defined `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`
So, try change this.

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID + " DESC", "8");
```

Comment: Could I do something like this if rows are less than 8, Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID + " DESC", "<=8");

Comment: @artist I don't know that. I know limit does not support '<', '>', '=', etc operators. I think if you want that, you can make function using cursor's value.